# Angular $http always returning null data from PHP API

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to use a login API that one of my developers created for me.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "http://example.com/api/userLogin",
    data: $.param(postLoginData),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    responseType: 'json'
}).then(function(loginData) {
    console.log(loginData);
});
```

My `console.log()` always logs the following:

```
Object {data: null, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}
```

Yet when I go to the `Network` tab within developer tools, I can see that the response is actually the following:

[image]

I'm not a backend developer, so I was a little confused with this `0` at the beginning of the response. I then tried to investigate this further and looked into the PHP API code itself, and found that the response from `curl_exec($loginCurl)` that is returned is:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 09 May 2016 02:10:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 43
Content-Type: application/json

{"id":"16","username":"user4","status":200}
```

The `body` of the response is valid JSON, so not too sure why Angular is returning null data, even though I can see the response in developer tools successfully...

---

**EDIT:**

My API contained the following to perform checks and create sessions:

```
$jsonResults = json_decode($body, true);
if($jsonResults != NULL || $jsonResults->id != NULL) {
    //Successfully logged in
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $jsonResults->username;
    $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $jsonResults->id;

    $this->response($body, 200);
}
```

Although, if the entire above code is just replaced with the following, it seems to work perfectly fine:

```
$this->response($body, 200);
```

Why would this be?

Comment: You can export a cURL command from the browser *Network* console (right-click on the *Name* -> Copy as cURL). Run that from your command line and see if the `0` shows up. The PHP script might be doing something based on user-agent or some other request header that your Angular app is sending

Comment: Also, you don't need to set `responseType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is definitely server-side however you can work around it using a response transformer. For example...

```
$http.post('http://example.com/api/userLogin', $.param(postLoginData), {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    transformResponse: function(data) {
        console.log('Raw data', data);
        if (angular.isString(data) && data[0] === '0') {
            data = data.substring(1);
        }
        return angular.fromJson(data);
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
})
```

Comment: I definitely thought this would fix my problem, although `data` always seems to be null - http://postimg.org/image/swlxybl6p/

Comment: Try adding some debugging to the transformer (see above)

Comment: @Fizzix did you try copying the cURL command from the browser?

Comment: Removing `responseType` allowed the data to come through, although having the `0` at the start of the data. Then your custom `transformResponse` converted it successfully. All working now, thanks Phil!

Comment: You're very right... quite dodgy isn't it. I'll attempt your cURL command thing now and get back to you.

Comment: Yes, while running as cURL in Terminal on my Mac, it has the `0` at the start of the response.

Comment: @Fizzix cool, at least you know where to look now (in the PHP). It could be as simple as an errant `0<?php` or something like that. I'd make sure you have [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) disabled, that might point to where the `0` is coming from

Comment: I reviewed all my code and could not find a mistaked 0 anywhere. Also set `output_buffering` to `Off`, and confirmed it was off with `phpinfo()`, yet still no luck removing that dreadful `0`.

Comment: Found it. There was a hidden `print_r()`. All good! Thanks for your help Phil.